# Create Entity Manager Factory without persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml, persistence-unit

Is there a way to create the **EntityManagerFactory without a persistence unit defined**? Can you give all the required properties to create an entity manager factory? I need to create the EntityManagerFactory from the user's specified values at runtime. Updating the persistence.xml and recompiling is not an option.

Currently I am using **eclipselink dynamic persistence** so i need to create the EntityManagerFactory without a persistence unit defined ? I have groups of runtime entities that need to map single group of entities to different database in runtime and no persistence unit entry is available for this runtime group of entities .

Any idea on how to do this is more than welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is most likely to access the PersistenceProvider directly and use the EJB container API to create the EntityManagerFactory from a PersistenceUnitInfo.

PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory()

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory%28javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo,%20java.util.Map%29

Comment: Thanks for your reply , May you classify PersistenceUnitInfo Interface  implementation class that need to passed in createContainerEntityManagerFactory() method .

Comment: Hello James Sutherland , May you provide direction/example-link for implementation class PersistenceUnitInfo Interface that need to passed in createContainerEntityManagerFactory() method as a arguments (that contains persistence unit info)

Comment: Check the JPA spec, it should cover the PersistecneUnitInfo specification

Answer (score -1):

Just seen in the DataNucleus documentation:

```
import org.datanucleus.metadata.PersistenceUnitMetaData;
import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory;

PersistenceUnitMetaData pumd = new PersistenceUnitMetaData("dynamic-unit", "RESOURCE_LOCAL", null);
pumd.addClassName("org.datanucleus.test.A");
pumd.setExcludeUnlistedClasses();
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:nucleus");
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "sa");
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
pumd.addProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "true");

EntityManagerFactory emf = new JPAEntityManagerFactory(pumd, null);
```

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/persistence_unit.html

Comment: This is specific to DataNucleus and not generic JPA.