# Hibernate: Replacement for Ejb3Configuration Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Sorry for the long back story but I wanted to give a good idea of why we're doing what we're doing.

Our application currently uses Hibernate 3.6 and we wish to upgrade to Hibernate 4.3.

The application was specifically written to avoid using `persistence.xml` to configure JPA and create the `EntityManagerFactory` and instead uses Hibernate's `Ejb3Configuration` class like this (example):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "RESOURCE_LOCAL");
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();
cfg.addProperties(properties);

DataSource dataSource = dataSourceProvider.get();
cfg.setDataSource(dataSource);

//add the annotated classes
cfg.addAnnotatedClass(SomePersistentObject.class);

EntityManagerFactory factory = cfg.buildEntityManagerFactory();
```

The reason we do it this way is because we have a web app (war file) deployed to Tomcat that provides "core" functionality.  Then, we install what we call "client bundles" which are jar files in the exploded `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.  The "client bundles" contain overrides to the existing "core" behavior of the web app.  This allows us to service multiple clients, each with various customizations from the "core" behavior, in one instance of the web app.  We know which client bundle to use based on the domain or subdomain of the incoming HTTP request.

Each client bundle always gets its own database instance, and thus each client bundle defines its own `EntityManagerFactory`.  The schemas are almost identical, although client bundles can add new persistent classes if needed.

So, the reason we do JPA configuration in Java is so that each client bundle extend the "core" classes and add their own entity classes.  Java is great for inheritance while XML stinks.  If we have to configure via XML, then each client bundle would need to copy the core's `persistence.xml` and update it from there. I would much rather use inheritance over copy/paste.

I think we have a pretty valid use case for preferring JPA configuration via Java rather than XML.

My question:  Does Hibernate 4.3 allow this in any way?  If so, how can I go about it?

If not, does anybody have any suggestions on how to make my above scenario as easy as possible while being stuck with XML configuration?

Can multiple jar files within a single web app contain `/META-INF/persistence.xml` files, or do multiple persistence units need to be defined another way?

Thank you!!!

-Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overcame the problem by dynamically writing a new `persistence.xml` file to the web app's classpath, before JPA is bootstrapped.

When the web app starts up, the JPA configuration for all the client bundles is read, and then a single `persistence.xml` file is written to the classpath.  Each client bundle gets its own entry as a `persistence-unit` within `persistence.xml`.

Then, after the new `persistence.xml` is written, JPA is bootstrapped.  JPA doesn't know or care, obviously, that the `persistence.xml` file was written dynamically.

It seems a little like a hack but I couldn't figure out any other way to do it.  One nice benefit is that it keeps me away from Hibernate specific APIs, so if I ever want to switch to something like DataNucleus as the JPA provider I will have the flexibility to do so.

Comment: I am not sure how many senior devs would recommend this approach versus using APIs to achieve the desired entity factory and configuration from (dynamic) sources.

Comment: @DarrellTeague, can you point me to some documentation on how this could be done using vendor-neutral APIs? Writing a `persistence.xml` dynamically isn't my first choice either, but I couldn't figure out how to do it using either JPA or Hibernate API's.  I have to stay away from vendor-specific API's because we use multiple JPA providers.  I'm sure JPA provides a way to do this, I just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: The Persistence class createEntityManagerFactory method can be used to get an EntityManager factory instance for a named persistence-unit and Map of properties. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29. Note that the Ejb3Configuration earlier cited is lately deprecated in lieu of this JPA-standardized approach. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939415/create-entity-manager-factory-without-persistence-xml